# Angular 4.3.x Routing Query Params failing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I have been trying to get query params working for the better part of two days and have had no luck. I have a very simple route def:

```
{ path: 'search', component: SearchComponent, canActivate: [ AuthGuard ] }
```

and I am trying to be able to come directly at the search page with query params that get looked at in the search controller and if they are there sets up the search properly from the query params:

```
http://localhost:5001/search?q=something&tt=234234234234
```

I have subscribed to the Activated route properly, I am even seeing the query params being parsed in console properly:

```
Object {q: "something", tt: "234234234234"}
```

but immediately after I am getting an error about not matching any route:

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'search%3Fq%3Dsomething%26tt%3D234234234234'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'search%3Fq%3Dsomething%26tt%3D234234234234'
```

Which I do get, there certainly isn't a route like that, why aren't the query params being extracted from the main route segment? I am using a main app module that loads up other modules. In my search module I am including the router module like:

```
RouterModule.forChild(searchRoutes)
```

My main router module has an empty route and is router module looks like:

```
{ path: '', component: AppComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }

RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
```

Both RouterModules are loaded at the end of imports. Thanks for any insight!

Comment: How are you navigating to the search route? Are you using a `RouterLink`? Or the `.navigate` method? What does the syntax of that look like?

Comment: what does you Authguard doing?

Comment: @DeborahK I suppose I am using a this.router.navigate(['/search']) from the app controller (first I check to see if I have a valid token to the rest-api we are using)

Comment: @JayDeeEss the Authguard actually only adds headers and pushes out our rest-api token, basically just adds that on to the current request. Well thats not fully accurate, the authguard just checks if there is a logged in user, there is also an interceptor that adds the headers and pushes the token on every request using httpClient

Comment: How are you setting the URL query parameters? Not as part of the `.navigate`?

Comment: @DeborahK, no manually in the URL. I need to be able to share links across users (copy/paste)

Comment: you know what @DeborahK, I think the problem may be that the url in the navigate is being set to '/search?q=something&tt=234234234234', so:

this.router.navigate(['/search?q=something&tt=234234234234'])

in which case thats my problem, that needs to be broken out doesn't it and passed as an object to .navigate

Comment: Yes. See my answer below. Otherwise the "?", "=", and "&" are being encoded as you see in the error message: `search%3Fq%3Dsomething%26tt%3D234234234234`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query parameters should be set as part of the `routerLink` or `.navigate` methods as shown here:

[image]

Comment: Ultimately the problem came down to the fact I was dynamically setting the redirect in a navigate() and the string portion of it included the query params. The issue here is that I expected the router's state snapshot url to not include query params, but they do. I ended up having to use the router's activated state snapshot (url[0].path) to get just "search"

I wonder if there is a method that grabs just this part from either state api?

Thanks for all your help Deborah!

Answer (score 0):

> Which I do get, there certainly isn't a route like that, why aren't the query params being extracted from the main route segment?

This is because you're using `pathMatch: 'full'`. Just remove it and see it working.

Comment: Originally I did not have pathMatch in there, same result.